# C# - Can I repeat SetSocketOption?

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, .net-2.0

I am trying to configure my UdpClient to reuse address and keep alive. Can I do the following?

```
UdpClient uClient = new UdpClient((IPEndPoint)net.ipLocalUDPEndPoint);
uClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
uClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft documentation example code calls it twice in a row.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.setsocketoption?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SetSocketOption);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2